# how to see client's ip address instead of hostname in remote syslogs

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng, syslog4j

my client machine has syslog-ng and my remote machine has rsyslog configuration.
my server/remote machine manages many clients and I need to differentiate which machine is sending which logs.
normally I would use syslog-ng on the server side but these machines aren't meant to have them.
Also would like to mention it isn't for apache or web servers just physical machines.

**On the client's side**

1. Tried altering and adding different options or changing them to yes/no respectively.

   ```
   options { 
   keep_hostname(yes);
   create_dirs(no);
   use_dns(no);
   };
   ```

   for eg:keep_hostname to no, it worked but only when I changed the hostname to the machine's ip address. which is not what I want.
2. Using a template

   ```
   template("$(ISODATE) $(FULLHOST_FROM) $(SOURCEIP) $(HOST) $(HOSTNAME) ${PROGRAM}: ${MESSAGE}\n")
   ```

   *output:*

   ```
   day time localhost abc[ID]  .source.s_local SourceIP=127.0.0.1 localhost localhost (root) CMD (xyz.conf)#ID
   ```

   this isn't the output I want, it is printing in the message section when I want it in the place of the "host" and I don't understand how the source ip is the loopback address.
3. Using structured logging

   ```
   rewrite r_sourceip{
   set('${SOURCEIP}' value(HOST));
   };
   ```

   ```
   log { source(s_local); rewrite(r_sourceip);destination(d_syslog_tcp); };
   ```

   *output:*
   and the ip is displayed in the logs as the loopback address instead of the machine ip.
   `day date time 127.0.0.1  syslog-ng.service: Succeeded.`
4. Tried installing rsyslog on my client but it doesn't work

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adiscon/v8-stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install rsyslog
   ```

   I kept running into many errors, fixing them was impossible due to the difference in OS version or type maybe.
   `add apt repository command not found`
   `wget command not found`

**On the server's side**

5. Using a template
   which creates a folder with the client's hostname and stores the logs in that particular folder.
   not the solution I want.

   ```
   $template DynaFile,"/var/log/%FROMHOST-IP%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
   *.* -?DynaFile
   ```

   ---

   I want the logs to appear as such

   ```
   day date time `client's ip address`  syslog-ng.service: Succeeded.
   ```

Can someone suggest me a solution and why I keep getting the loopback address as my client's ip?

Comment: This Q is not about `if-tnen-else` programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on [unix.se] OR [sf] .   Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good Luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank you so much for the advice, I will alter and post in a more appropiate website.